# Return even numbers

Tags: java, recursion

I'm a newbie here and just want to know how to return only even digits. And that without using while or for.

```
public static long evenDigit(long digit){
    return ((digit < 10 && digit % 2 == 0) 
            || ((digit % 10) % 2 == 0)
            ? 
            : evenDigit(digit / 10));
}
```

I'm getting a StackOverflowError. And I think it's because of the line behind the ?. It will recurse infinitely. I don't really know what to do right now. So maybe you guys have some tips?

edit: okay change the name of the method. Now it's probably more clear.

So this was btw a method from an exam last year. To print out only even digits. Using recursion. In this style.

Comment: What does the `odd` function supposed to return is not clear

Comment: What even number is it *supposed* to return for a given input? Also, why is the method named `odd` if it is supposed to return a single *even* number?

Comment: only even numbers among which numbers? The method only take one number, and can only return one. So, what precisely should the method do?

Comment: BTW: Of course it throws StackOverflowError, since it'll *always* call itself recursively. Recursive methods need a [stop condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_termination), that will stop the recursion. Your method doesn't have that.

Comment: My name is kinda dumb, I know. I just want to write out odd numbers. I have in the main method a system print out with the numbers: 123456
And I want only 246 to return.

Just bear with me guys, I'm super new to all of this and I really wanna learn java.

Comment: Ok, so you want to *remove* all odd *digits* from a number, i.e. keep only the even *digits*, right? Watch your terminology: `123` is a single *number* consisting of 3 *digits*. It is not 3 numbers.

Comment: you could convert the double to String, extract the even/odd elements, then convert back to double

Comment: Okay digit, not number. Simple translation fail.

Comment: @BlondesGift Updated question is not more clear. Parameter is a *number*, not a single digit, and method should retain only even *digits*, so a better signature would be `evenDigits(long number)`. --- Also, showing sample input/output, like you did in the comment, helps clarify what you want/expect.

Comment: The code as currently given will not even compile.

Comment: Andreas comment is the solution (thank you again). I'm sorry for being not clear enough. And you are right. Next time I have to write the input/output. Sorry again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51123956/return-even-numbers#comment89233079_51123956):

> I have in the main method a system print out with the numbers: `123456`
>   And I want only `246` to return.

First, you need to determine the stop condition, to ensure the recursion will terminate. If the input is only 1 digit, it shouldn't recurse:

```
if (number < 10) { // only one digit
    if (number % 2 == 0)
        return number; // keep even digit
    return 0; // discard odd digit
}
```

Now, since number has multiple digits, we need to decide if we want to keep the last digit, then make recursive call on higher-order digits:

```
if (number % 2 != 0)
    return odd(number / 10); // Discard last digit and process other digits

return odd(number / 10) * 10 // process other digits
     + number % 10;          // keeping last digit
```

The above can be abbreviated to:

```
public static long odd(long number) {
    return (number < 10 ? (number % 2 == 0 ? number : 0) :
            number % 2 != 0 ? odd(number / 10) : odd(number / 10) * 10 + number % 10);
}
```

Comment: Okay this is it! Thank you so much. It's also super good explained.